# Label selector vs namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, containers

It seems there is 2 ways to logically group pods, which are:

- using labels to identifies organizational units in a loosely coupled fashion
- creating namespaces

What are exactly the differences and use cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's begin with a cluster which consists a number of nodes(Virtual Machines or Physical Machines ). Now We will divide our cluster in a logical way

**Namespaces**  is a virtual cluster or a logical cluster. It helps us to organise projects or environments (development, testing, staging, and production environments). 
By using **Namespaces**, You can limit the quota to each namespace for resources utilization. You want to be sure that production environment has more than enough resources, so it won't starve to death.

**Labels** is a powerful concept in Kubernetes.It's a key-value pair which is assigned to kubernetes resources such as Pods, RepicaSet, Node etc. It is used to organise pods.for instance, ReplicaSet or Service can select the  pods in a k8s cluster by using labels and perform an operation on them such as increasing the number of pods.

I have attached the link for further reading [labels and Selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) and [Namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/)